# Get the actual month difference between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I working with strange queries in SQL, I want to find the actual month difference between two dates, for example

```
StartDate = '1-1-2013'
EndDate = '4-30-2013'
```

Here I want result to be 4 not 3

```
select datediff(mm, '1-1-2013', '4-30-2013')
```

This query will provide me result 3 but actual result is 4. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Why do you want the result to be 4? I assume that SQL Server is truncating the result (i.e. finding the greatest number of months such that "start + months <= end"). If you add 4 months to January 1st you get May 1st, which "overshoots" the target.

Comment: The query is correct, the time difference is 3 months and 29 days?

Comment: Given 30 April is the end of April, then 1 Jan to 30 Apr can be seen as four months, I'd have thought. The next day would make it exactly four months.

Comment: What should the difference between `1-1-2013` and `4-29-2013` be computed as?

Comment: There's a lot of variations and interpretations here. The important part would be for the OP to post *why* he wants 4, and *when* he wants that rule to apply, because otherwise the only valid answer is "Well, then add 1".

Comment: it all depends on how you define a month. Date arithmetic is awful actually. (Think about: what's jan 30 + 1 month? what's jan 30 + 2 months? what's jan 30 + 1 month + 1 month?). Anyway, you might want to have something like select datediff(dd, '1-1-2013', '4-30-2013')/30. But whatever rule you define, dates will manage to get it wrong :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet - no, SQL Server's `DATEDIFF` counts transitions. `DATEDIFF(month,'20130131','20130201')` is 1, because there's one month transition between the two dates - despite them only being a day apart.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Ooh, interesting - thanks for that. Transitions doesn't seem terribly useful to me :(

Comment: @JonSkeet this syntax is very useful. Especially when you need to find a specific numbered day(example first day of current month): dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp), 0). It is however not useful to calculate the exact difference between 2 dates, unless applying some additional logic

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this helps but here's my stab at it:

```
declare
    @date1 datetime = '2013-01-01',
    @date2 datetime = '2013-04-30'

select Cast(Round(Cast(DATEDIFF(DD,@date1, @date2) as decimal(5,2)) / 30, 1) as int)   as  Months
```

Comment: If month complete o 31 then what happen

Comment: this gives a rounded value, in the example above it's 3.96(6) and I'm rounding after the first digit (to get the desired result of 4)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add 01-01-2013 and 04-30-2013 instead of what you added here

So query  will be as below

```
select datediff(mm, '1-1-2013', '4-30-2013')
```

Thanks
Vasanthan

Comment: this suggestion will not make a difference, and it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't as simple as it first appears. One obvious way would be to add one day to your end date before doing the datediff. This would then be doing 1 Jan to 1 May which would be reported as four months.

However you need to consider if there's any tolerances; for example, should 1 Jan to 29 Apr be considered four months, or is that still three months? Obviously this will depend heavily on the context in which you are using these dates.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the result is absolutely correct: 3 months and 29 days.

You can of course check if the date in the end date is the last date of the month and make an adjustment to produce the desired result:

```
DECLARE @START DATETIME, @END DATETIME
SELECT @START = '2014-01-01', @END = '2014-04-30'

SELECT @START, @END

SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @START, CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @END)) > MONTH(@END) THEN DATEADD(DAY, +1, @END) ELSE @END END)
```

Not sure about the performance of said example (you're free to experiment with similar ideas), but what it does is add the last missing day to produce the 4 month difference whenever the end date represents the last day of that month.

Now, I agree with the others here that this is a weird thing to do, but if this is what your case requires, then so be it. We can't really comment on your business / programming specific needs here. :)